# Admin account has insufficient privileges to create app user

Tags: c#, box

I am trying to create a Windows app (.Net, C#) that will get a list of files in the Box.com folder passed in.  Apparently one of the steps in configuring a new Box app using JWT authorization is to create an App User with the SDK (Box.V2).  I took the following code from some examples in the SDK documentation.  The CreateEnterpriseUserAsync() call is failing with the error message:

> BoxException: Bearer realm="Service", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."

I'm the account admin, so I should have all rights.  However, I'm using a developer account with just one seat. . . not sure if that's the limitation.  I'd be grateful for any help!

The error is happening about 3/4 of the way down the sample, where indicated.

```cs
namespace Trial5
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = Configure();
        t.Wait();
    }

    private static async Task Configure()
    {
            // Open a stream to read the Box configuration file.
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream($"./BoxConfig.json", FileMode.Open))
            {

            //configure  -----------------------------------------------------------------
            var boxConfig = BoxConfig.CreateFromJsonFile(fs);
            var boxJWT = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig); 

            //authenticate   -----------------------------------------------------------------
            var adminToken = boxJWT.AdminToken(); //valid for 60 minutes so should be cached and re-used
            var adminClient = boxJWT.AdminClient(adminToken);

            // Use the GetCurrentUserInformationAsync method to retrieve current user's information.
            // Since this client uses the Service Account, this will return the Service Account's information.
            var adminClientInfo = await adminClient.UsersManager.GetCurrentUserInformationAsync();
            //See the login
            Console.WriteLine(adminClientInfo.Login);

            //create app user  -----------------------------------------------------------------
            //NOTE: you must set IsPlatformAccessOnly=true for an App User
            var userRequest = new BoxUserRequest() { Name = "test appuser1", IsPlatformAccessOnly = true };
            var appUser = await adminClient.UsersManager.CreateEnterpriseUserAsync(userRequest);  // <---------------ERROR HERE

            //get a user client  -----------------------------------------------------------------
            var userToken = boxJWT.UserToken(appUser.Id); //valid for 60 minutes so should be cached and re-used
            var userClient = boxJWT.UserClient(userToken, appUser.Id);

            //for example, look up the app user's details
            var userClientInfo = await userClient.UsersManager.GetCurrentUserInformationAsync();

            //Get folder info
            var items = await userClient.FoldersManager.GetFolderItemsAsync("0", 500);

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Dear @kendoman, you've been my guru before. Could I trouble you again?

Comment: Notifications only work when the user in question was active inside the topic itself, you cannot just ping users from any topic available. You will have to debug a bit to see where your code fails, and then come back with a specific error, not just mention that if fails 3 quarters down the code, that's well, a bit to easy on your part

Comment: @Icepickle, I learned about the tagging you mentioned after I did it. My apologies.  However, I spent hours trying to debug it myself. I presented my entire source code (which could be pasted into a blank project), gave you the full text of the error message I received and indicated where it occurred.  Not sure how much more I could have done.

Answer (score 1):

If you check "Manager Users" scope on the app console and then reauthorize your app in the enterprise admin console under "Apps", it should work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't think to try reauthorizing.  I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.  Really appreciate your help. (Sorry I misspelled your name above!)